# Two apparently unrelated questions with the same answer

Tags: discussion, questions, self-answer

I've been struggling with a BizTalk problem for well over a day now and finally discovered that the answer is a simple registry change.  In order to stop people wasting their time like I have, I planned to use SO to document this by answering my own question.

I searched SO to ensure it wasn't already documented, and discovered that the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840699/biztalk-bre-invalidcastexception) is the fix I used.  However the question itself is rather unrelated and no one is likely to find it by searching for terms relevant to my issue.

I suppose there are numerous options here:

- Post a new question and answer it with a similar answer
- Post a new question and answer it by linking to the existing answer
- Edit the existing question to show that the same answer can apply to both scenarios

What is the accepted way of handling this to reduce duplication and to ensure that others can find the answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd post your version of the question and answer on your own(might want to add a note that you will be answering it).